# Whats an alternative to using a cursor as per this example in t-sql

Tags: t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, cursor

I’m new to SQL (specifically t-sql and microsoft SQL Server 2008 R2) and had a problem my boss advised me to fix using a cursor. The problem being taking records (equating to shifts entered into a roster) that are over an hour (but divisible by an hour) and effectively splitting them into multiple shift records of an hour each for a report.

Below you can see the section of the query re the cursor logic that I used. My understanding is that cursors are very inefficient and frowned upon – but neither my boss nor myself could identify an alternative solution to this problem.

Can anyone demonstrate a way we could do this without cursors?

```
Open Curs;

 FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @ClientID, @RDNSID, @SvceType, @SDate, @ClientNm, @CHours, @StaffNm, @Package

WHILE (@@Fetch_Status = 0)
BEGIN
      SET @Hour = 60
      SET @Num = @Chours
    IF (@Num % 60 = 0)
            BEGIN
                  WHILE (@Num >= 60)
                  BEGIN
                        INSERT INTO #ASRTable VALUES (@ClientID, @RDNSID, @SvceType, @SDate, @ClientNm, @Hour, @StaffNm, @Package)
                        SET @Num = @Num - 60
                        SET @SDate = DATEADD(HH, 1, @SDate)
                  END
            END

      ELSE
            BEGIN
                  SET @Hour = 'INVALID SHIFT'
                  INSERT INTO #ASRTable VALUES (@ClientID, @RDNSID, @SvceType, @SDate, @ClientNm, @Hour, @StaffNm, @Package)
            END

      FETCH NEXT FROM Curs INTO @ClientID, @RDNSID, @SvceType, @SDate, @ClientNm, @CHours, @StaffNm, @Package
END


SELECT * FROM #ASRTable

DROP TABLE #ASRTable   

CLOSE Curs
DEALLOCATE Curs
```

Comment: Well, you've managed to **omit** the most interesting part - the **cursor definition** .... (`DECLARE CURSOR Curs FOR ......` ). Also, can you explain in plain English what this code is supposed to be doing? That's usual quite helpful to understand what's going on...

Answer (score 1):

Well, you haven't given us sample data or expected results, but I think this follows the same logic:

```
declare @t table (
    SDate datetime not null,
    Chours int not null --Curiously, will store a number of minutes?
)

insert into @t (SDate,Chours) values ('2012-12-19T10:30:00',120),('2012-12-18T09:00:00',60),('2012-12-17T08:00:00',90)

;with shifts as (
    select SDate,Chours,'60' as Hour from @t where Chours % 60 = 0
    union all
    select DATEADD(hour,1,SDate),CHours - 60,'60' from shifts where Chours > 0
)
select SDate,Hour from shifts
union all
select SDate,'Invalid Shift' from @t where CHours % 60 <> 0
```

Result:

```
SDate                   Hour
----------------------- -------------
2012-12-19 10:30:00.000 60
2012-12-18 09:00:00.000 60
2012-12-18 10:00:00.000 60
2012-12-19 11:30:00.000 60
2012-12-19 12:30:00.000 60
2012-12-17 08:00:00.000 Invalid Shift
```

Of course, I don't have all of your other columns, since I have no idea what they're meant to be.

Comment: Thanks folks - I will give more information with my answer next time. Thanks for the example Damien - will give it a berl!